# sklearn kmeans predict ValueError on sample size

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, k-means

i have trained my KMeans model

```
clf = KMeans( n_clusters = num_clusters )
km = clf.fit_predict(model.docvecs)
```

where model.docvecs is a list of 200 numpy arrays od dimensions 100.

example

```
len(model.docvecs) = 200
len(model.docvecs[0] = 100

    model.docvecs:
    [[ -3.97457965e-02   9.68865305e-03  -3.20274942e-02  -5.41459583e-03
       6.67170063e-02   9.20293033e-02   3.16953734e-02  -2.13479511e-02
       1.87820643e-02  -2.44720243e-02   2.16792207e-02  -2.09533237e-02..]
    [ -3.97457965e-02   9.68865305e-03  -3.20274942e-02  -5.41459583e-03
       6.67170063e-02   9.20293033e-02   3.16953734e-02  -2.13479511e-02
       1.87820643e-02  -2.44720243e-02   2.16792207e-02  -2.09533237e-02..]..]
```

Now i want to predict which cluster a single vector belongs to. 
new_vec is a 100 dimension vector - like the other vectors.

```
new_vec = [ -3.97457965e-02   9.68865305e-03  -3.20274942e-02  -5.41459583e-03
       6.67170063e-02   9.20293033e-02   3.16953734e-02  -2.13479511e-02
       1.87820643e-02  -2.44720243e-02   2.16792207e-02  -2.09533237e-02..]
```

my code:

```
km.fit(new_vec.reshape(1,-1))
```

This is my error:

```
--> 789                 X.shape[0], self.n_clusters))
    790         return X
    791 

ValueError: n_samples=1 should be >= n_clusters=100
```

cant seem to figure it out

Comment: You are trying to create `k > n` clusters. For example, you might be trying to cram 5 rows into 10 boxes. Do you see why you can't do that in KMeans (which doesn't allow for cluster overlap)? Other unsupervised learning approaches, e.g. `sklearn.decomposition.NMF` allow for overlapping of "themes"/"groups".

Comment: i switched to `km.predict(new_vec.reshape(1,-1))`
and it returned a cluster value. Is it safe to say that the predict method just finds the centroid nearest to the new data?